# python - Union/Merging nested dict and list to get value type

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an issue like this,
I have a dictionary:

```
{
   "histories":[
      {
         "id":"22167",
         "author":{
            "displayName":"Mommy"
         },
         "items":[
            {
               "field":"resolution",
               "fieldtype":"jira",
            },
            {
               "field":"status",
               "from":"10090",
               "fromString":"Work in progress",
               "to":"10001",
               "toString":"Done"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"22131",
         "author":{
            "displayName":"Daddy"
         },
         "created":"2020-02-28T10:04:22.433+0700",
         "items":[
            {
               "field":"assignee",
               "tmpToAccountId":"5c5c29b75bb21413fc41d39b"
            },
            {
               "field":"status",
               "fieldtype":"jira",
               "fieldId":"status",
               "from":"1",
               "fromString":"Open",
               "to":"10090",
               "toString":"Work in progress"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need the pair of key and value type mapping information of all nested object/list in the list of dictionary to be something like this:

```
{
   "histories":[
      {
         "id":str,
         "author":{
            "displayName":str
         },
         "created":str,
         "items":[
            {
               "field":str,
               "fieldtype":str,
               "fieldId":str,
               "from":str,
               "fromString":str,
               "to":str,
               "toString":str,
               "tmpToAccountId":str

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

So I can get all of the keys and value types from this dictionary

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see a need for recursive function here, unless you forgot to mention some additional details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**UPDATE:**

```
import json

def map_dict(dictionary):
    result = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result[key] = map_dict(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            result[key] = []
            result[key].append(map_dict(value[0]))
        else:
            result[key] = type(value).__name__

    return result

def merge_dicts(*dict_args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in dict_args:
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if isinstance(value, list):
                merged = merge_dicts(*value)
                dictionary[key].clear()
                dictionary[key].append(merged)

        result.update(dictionary)

    return result

def merge_and_map(*dict_args):
    merged = merge_dicts(*dict_args)
    mapped = map_dict(merged)
    return [mapped]

info["histories"] = merge_and_map(*info["histories"])
print(json.dumps(info, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "histories": [
        {
            "id": "str",
            "author": {
                "displayName": "str"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "field": "str",
                    "tmpToAccountId": "str",
                    "fieldtype": "str",
                    "fieldId": "str",
                    "from": "str",
                    "fromString": "str",
                    "to": "str",
                    "toString": "str"
                }
            ],
            "created": "str"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I meant to merge cross parent too. Updated the question

Comment: And what is the basis for such merging - the same value for key `"id"`?

Comment: @Błotosmętek From my original question, there is no basis, just random and make sure it's not null value, because I need the value type. But I just updated the question, so my objective to be more clear.

Comment: @GoldanLevitt Updated the answer according to your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
x = {<your input dict here>}

for i, value in enumerate(x["histories"]):
    new_items = {}
    for item in x["histories"][i]["items"]:
        new_items.update(item)
    x["histories"][i]["items"] = [new_items]

pprint.pprint(x)
```

There's duplicate keys in the "items" list dictionaries, so if you need them all, I don't see this as the best way. You can write it to handle duplicates and rename them or keep the same key name and add them to the value as a list.